# Angular-chart in md-grid-list dont work on firefox

Tags: angularjs, firefox, canvas, angular-material, angular-chart

This is part of my code:

```
    <md-grid-list md-cols-xs="2" md-cols-sm="3" md-cols-md="3" md-cols-gt-md="6" md-row-height="7:8" md-gutter="12px" md-gutter-gt-sm="8px">
    <md-grid-tile ng-repeat="pieChart in pieChartsData" class="main flex-wraper" md-rowspan="1" md-colspan="1" md-colspan-sm="1" md-colspan-xs="1">
        <div flex="100" class="flex-wraper" ng-click="onMonthClick(pieChart)">
            <div flex="100"><h4 style="text-align: center;">{{pieChart.Label}}</h4></div>
            <div flex="100" class="flex-wraper"><canvas class="chart chart-pie" chart-data="pieChart.Data" chart-labels="pieChart.Labels" flex="100"></canvas></div>
        </div>
    </md-grid-tile>
</md-grid-list>
```

Working fine on Chrome, but in Firefox chart wont display... No error, nothing in console.

Comment: Without md-grid-list working fine on FF

Comment: Stop - i have error : Error: No response from frame: #app-navbar > .md-padding.layout-column.flex > .ng-scope > .ng-isolate-scope._md > md-grid-tile:nth-of-type(3) > figure > .flex-wraper.ng-scope.flex-100 > .flex-wraper.flex-100 > .chartjs-hidden-iframe